# Simultaneously Normalising Row-Wise and Column-Wise Sum

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and want to normalise its column-wise and row-wise sums. This is only possible if the numbers we normalise the sums to are not 1 but $m$ and $n$ respectively (or some multiple of these). That is

$$
\sum_{i} A_{ij} w_{ij} = m, \qquad \sum_{j} A_{ij} w_{ij} = n.
$$

Additionally, I require that the weights be on the form $w_{ij} = a_ib_j$ which puts restrictions on the number of degrees of freedom in my equations. My question is this, when is this problem solvable? For which matrices $A$ and shapes $m \times n$ are there solutions to this and how many are there if any? Are there explicit formulas for the possible solutions or how do I go about finding weights that solve the problem above?

I have gotten this far on my own:

$$
  \begin{align}
    \sum_{j} A_{ij} w_{ij} = n, & \qquad \sum_{i} A_{ij} w_{ij} = m \\
    \sum_{j} A_{ij} a_ib_j = n, & \qquad \sum_{i} A_{ij} a_ib_j = m \\
    b_j\sum_{j} A_{ij} a_i = n, & \qquad a_i\sum_{i} A_{ij} b_j = m \\
    \sum_{j} A_{ij} a_i = n/b_j, & \qquad \sum_{i} A_{ij} b_j = m/a_i \\
    Aa = n/b, & \qquad A^Tb = m/a,
  \end{align}
$$

where $a = [a_1, \cdots, a_n]^T$, $b = [b_1, \cdots, b_m]^T$ and we take $c/\gamma$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^p$ to mean $[c/\gamma_1, \cdots, c/\gamma_p]^T$.

If $m>n$, then the left equation of the bottom row isn't generally solvable (m equations with n degrees of freedom). However, I have a handwavy feeling that there exists a subspace, $S$, of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that for $b \in S$ the left equation is solvable and additionally the right equations always has a solution in $S$.

EDIT: The entries of $A$ are non-negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classical *matrix scaling* problem. See e.g. Theorem 3.1 of [the review article by Idel (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06349):

> Let $A ∈ \mathbb R^{m×n}$ be a matrix with nonnegative entries. Then for any vectors $r ∈ \mathbb R^m$ and $c ∈ \mathbb R^n$ with nonnegative numbers there exist diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ such that
> $$D_1 AD_2e = r\\
> D_2 A^T D_1e = c$$
> if and only if there exists a matrix $B$ with $Be = r$ and $B^T e = c$ and the same pattern [of nonzeros] as $A$. Here, $e = (1, . . . , 1)^T$ which means that $r$ contains the row sums of the scaled matrix and $c$ contains the column sums.
>
> Furthermore, if the matrix has only positive entries, $D_1$ and $D_2$ are unique up to a constant factor.

Comment: +1 for the reference, but it isn't accurate to say that the theorem you've mentioned is the one in the OP, because the matrix in the OP isn't required to be nonnegative.

Comment: My matrix is in fact non-negative (forgot to mention this) and it seems to me that the second criteria ($Be = r$ and $B^Te = c$) is always true for my choice of $r$ and $c$ ($m$, $n$ and $B$ full of ones). This would mean that the diagonal matrices exist and my problem has a solution (please correct me if I'm wrong). Thanks for the reference, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

*(Too long for a comment.)* You are essentially asking whether there exist two diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ such that in $B=D_1AD_2$, all column sums are equal to $m$ and all row sums are equal to $n$. This is not always possible. I can see at least two difficulties here.

First, the possible sparseness of $A$ can be problematic. In the most extreme case, if $A$ has a zero row, the row sum remains zero no matter how you adjust the weights.

Second, the dimension of $A$ itself may further complicate the problem. Consider $A=\pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\ 0&1&0&1}$ for instance. If you want all column sums of $B=D_1AD_2$ to be equal to $m=2$, then $B$ must be equal to $2A$. But then the row sums of $B$ are equal to $2\ne 4=n$.

At any rate, there is an algorithm, known as Sinkhorn-Knopp algorithm, that modifies every nonnegative *square* matrix  $A\ne0$ with total support (i.e., every positive element of $A$ lies on a positive transversal) by two diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ to a doubly stochastic matrix $B=D_1AD_2$. So, for such an $A$, the answer to your question is affirmative.